# Common Ancestor to Java Array and List

Tags: java, enumerable

In .NET, both array and list have Enumerable as ancestor, so a method that accept Enumerable as an argument can receive both array and list as its argument.
I wonder if there is a similar thing in Java?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent in Java. I would generally suggest that you design API methods to receive `List<T>`, `Collection<T>` or `Iterable<T>`. While these preclude *directly* calling the method with an array, you can wrap an array very easily using `Arrays.asList`. This is more flexible for the caller than specifying an array as a method parameter, which forces a single implementation.

I agree it's not ideal though.

Note that in .NET, single-dimensional arrays don't just implement `IEnumerable<T>` - they implement `IList<T>` as well.

Answer (score 4):

They don't have a common ancestor, however, there are methods to cast between the two types as needed -

- [List.toArray()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))
- [Arrays.asList()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

So you could provide an overloaded method to cast to a common type - i.e.

```
public void doAll(MyType[] array) {
    doAll(Arrays.asList(array));
}

public void doAll(List<MyType> list) {
    //... process List here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array and List in Java do not share a common ancestor other than java.lang.Object.

Both can be accessed using the foreach loop, like so:

```
String [] array = new String [] { "foo", "bar", "baz", };
List<String> list = Arrays.asList( "x", "y", "z");

for (String s : array)
    System.out.println(s);

for (String s : list)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, arrays have an implicit type that is a subclass of object. See [Arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html) in the JLS:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] ia = new int[3];
            System.out.println(ia.getClass());
            System.out.println(ia.getClass().getSuperclass());
   }

   > class [I
   > class java.lang.Object
```

The way arrays and lists are handled is also not the same when we consider [**covariance/contravariance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Overview_of_covariance.2Fcontravariance_in_some_programming_languages).

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<String>(); // complain 
Object[] l2 = new String[1]; // ok

l2[0] = 4; // throw ArrayStoreException.
```

It gets even worse if we consider generics, but that's another topic. All in all, I don't know the rationale of this design, but we need to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Both derive from `java.lang.Object`. However, this isn't collection-related, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterable<T>` is the Java equivalent of `IEnumerable<T>`. All/most collections implement this interface (including `ArrayList` and arrays), so yes. But it's not an "ancestor" (which it's not in .NET either), but a common interface.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Arrays do not implement Iterable.